# Mac App Store installation limit?

Tags: macos, installation, mac-app-store

Is there any limitation of installation of apps purchased from Mac App Store?

Comment: You mean a limitation of the number of apps **Apple lets you download in exchange for your hard-earned money**? No. They take all the money you throw at them (it's called a business model). Just make sure you have enough free disk space.

Comment: See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/can-i-install-apps-bought-on-appstore-on-multiple-computers

Comment: This **isn't** `Off Topic` IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By my reading* of [the App Store Terms and Conditions](http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/uk/terms.html#APPS), unless you're a business or educational institution, you can install App Store applications on any Macs you own ("*You may download and use an application from the Mac App Store (“Mac App Store Product”) for personal, non-commercial use on any Apple-branded products running Mac OS X (“Mac Computer”) that you own or control.*"). I don't believe the five-computer restriction that applies to iTunes downloads exists for the Mac App Store.

*but [IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL)

Comment: See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/can-i-install-apps-bought-on-appstore-on-multiple-computers -- yes, you can install App Store purchased apps on every Mac you own. No limits as long as they're personal use machines.

Answer (score 1):

No, except for your free hard drive space.